# Share a video on YouTube with another user

Tags: youtube, sharing

How do I share a YouTube video with **another YouTube user**?

I don't mean sharing via email. I mean sharing on the site itself, with a specific user name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click the share link you should have the option to share via username as well as email address.

1. From the video you wish to share click the 'Share' link
2. At the bottom of the box 'Send this video from YouTube'
3. Enter username and optional message
4. Send

Help Video - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xoZV-BtJjXw

Comment: http://imgur.com/k3MSp.png I only get email + social networks...

Comment: @Brainfeeder - click on email, you will then have the option to send to username.

Comment: Wow thanks. Awesome user interface design... *facepalm*

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore, that field only accepts e-mail addresses. It seems like the only way to do it is to go through [private messages on the user's page](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/57955?hl=en).

Comment: Awesome interface indeed! Goble wants to spam you with useless notifications, not the useful ones.